# When answering a greeting one should top it

Tags: sources-mekorot, talmud-gemara

On a daf yomi shiur I heard that when someone is being greeted/blessed he should reply with a greater blessing.

When I heard that I thought that this was the reason why people reply shabbat shalom umevorach then they are told shabbat shalom

Where can I find this gemora?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_Chasidim.18.1?lang=he לעולם המשיב כופל השלום

Comment: @JoelK thank you very much this idea is in the gemora derech agav https://www.sefaria.org/Gittin.62a.12 I need to read the rest of the page

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27448/170

Comment: @JoelK בחזרה שאז הסברא נותנת להכפיל לו שלום ע"ד שאנו אומרים למי שנותן לחבירו צפרא טבא הואי משיב לו שנה טובה https://www.sefaria.org/Drisha%2C_Yoreh_Deah.148.6